# Processing multiple text files concurrently

Tags: python, multiprocessing, gevent, libevent

*Resolved by using pool.map() instead of map_async() with multiprocessing.

Python 2.7 - How do I get gevent or multiprocessing to process multiple text files at the same time with the following code?

I've pasted both gevent and multiprocessing pool versions

From the log output it shows the files are being processed synchronously and using 'lsof' on Linux confirms only one file is being read at once time.

The files are stored on a enterprise class disk shelf containing an array of ultra320 drives.

I can open 4 files at once with the following function that just sleeps, just not when I try the process the open file line by line. Is the 'for line in file' loop preventing the next file from being opened somehow?

```py
from time import sleep
from multiprocessing import Pool


def hold_open(log):
    with open(log) as fh:
        sleep(60)

pool = Pool(processes=4)
pool.map(hold_open, ['file1', 'file2', 'file3', 'file4'])
pool.join()
```

What am I doing wrong and what do I change to fix it?

```
2014-10-07 13:51:51,088 - __main__ - INFO - Found 23 files, duration: 0:00:00.000839
2014-10-07 13:51:51,088 - __main__ - INFO - Now analysing using 8 threads.....
2014-10-07 13:51:51,089 - __main__ - INFO - XSLog2014.05.15-16.40.01.txt - Analysing...
2014-10-07 13:51:51,471 - __main__ - INFO - XSLog2014.05.15-16.40.01.txt - Finished analysing 41943107 bytes duration: 0:00:00.381875
2014-10-07 13:51:51,471 - __main__ - INFO - XSLog2014.09.18-23.53.59.txt.gz - Analysing...
2014-10-07 13:51:53,197 - __main__ - INFO - XSLog2014.09.18-23.53.59.txt.gz - Finished analysing 4017126 bytes duration: 0:00:01.725641
2014-10-07 13:51:53,197 - __main__ - INFO - XSLog2014.09.30-11.45.44.txt.gz - Analysing...
2014-10-07 13:51:54,950 - __main__ - INFO - XSLog2014.09.30-11.45.44.txt.gz - Finished analysing 4970479 bytes duration: 0:00:01.753434
2014-10-07 13:51:54,950 - __main__ - INFO - XSLog2014.09.30-11.46.05.txt.gz - Analysing...
```

```py
from gevent import monkey; monkey.patch_all()
import os
import re
import gzip
import gevent
import logging
from gevent import pool
from datetime import datetime


log_level = logging.INFO
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(log_level)
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(log_level)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
ch.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(ch)


def get_time_range(log):
    if not os.path.isfile(log):
        logging.error("\x1b[31m%s - Something went wrong analysing\x1b[0m" % log)
        return
    date_regex = re.compile('^(\d{4}\.\d{2}\.\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{3})')

    def process(lh):
        start, end = str(), str()
        logger.info("\x1b[33m%s - Analysing...\x1b[0m" % os.path.basename(log))
        for line in lh:
            date = date_regex.match(line)
            if date:
                if not start:
                    start = date.group(1)
                end = date.group(1)
        return start, end
    start_time = datetime.now()
    size = os.path.getsize(log)
    if os.path.splitext(log)[1] == '.txt':
        with open(log, 'r') as lh:
            start, end = process(lh)
    elif os.path.splitext(log)[1] == '.gz':
        with gzip.open(log, 'r') as lh:
            start, end = process(lh)
    else:
        return
    meta = (log, size, start, end)
    duration = datetime.now() - start_time
    logger.info("\x1b[32m%s - Finished analysing %s bytes duration: %s\x1b[0m" % (os.path.basename(log), size, duration))


def run(directory, pool_size=8, cur=None):
    start = datetime.now()
    worker_pool = gevent.pool.Pool(int(pool_size))
    files = list()
    while True:
        for log in os.listdir(directory):
            if 'XSLog' and 'txt' in log:
                files.append(os.path.join(directory, log))
        logger.info("\x1b[36mFound %s files, duration: %s\x1b[0m" % (len(files), datetime.now() - start))
        logger.info("\x1b[36mNow analysing using %s threads.....\x1b[0m" % pool_size)
        for log in files:
            worker_pool.spawn(get_time_range, log)
        worker_pool.join()
        duration = datetime.now() - start
        logger.info("\x1b[36mFinished analysing - duration: %s\x1b[0m" % duration)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run('/path/to/log/files')
```

With multiprocessing:

```py
def run(directory, pool_size=8, cur=None):
    start = datetime.now()
    worker_pool = gevent.pool.Pool(int(pool_size))
    files = list()
    pool = Pool(processes=pool_size, maxtasksperchild=2)
    while True:
        for log in os.listdir(directory):
            if 'XSLog' and 'txt' in log:
                files.append(os.path.join(directory, log))
        logger.info("\x1b[36mFound %s files, duration: %s\x1b[0m" % (len(files), datetime.now() - start))
        logger.info("\x1b[36mNow analysing using %s threads.....\x1b[0m" % pool_size)
        # pool.map_async(get_time_range, files)
        pool.map(get_time_range, files) # This fixed it.
        pool.join()
        duration = datetime.now() - start
        logger.info("\x1b[36mFinished analysing - duration: %s\x1b[0m" % duration)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The amount of benefit you get from parallelism is limited here, because a significant chunk of your time is spent reading from disk. Disk I/O is sequential; it doesn't matter how many processes/greenlets you have, only one of them is going to be able to read from disk at a time. Now, aside from the time spent reading from disk, the rest of the time is spent doing a regular expression match on the lines being read. `gevent` will not help you *at all* for this. It's a CPU-bound operation, and `gevent` can't be used to parallelize CPU-bound operations. `gevent` is useful for making blocking I/O operations non-blocking, which enables parallel I/O, but there is no blocking I/O going on here.

`multiprocessing` *can* make the regex operations run in parallel, so I would expect it to perform a little bit better than the `gevent` version. But in either case, you're probably not going to be much (if any) faster than a sequential version, because so much of your time is spent reading the file from disk.

Comment: I've edited the original post to include an aspect I overlooked.The files are stored on an enterprise class disk shelf so in most cases, depending on the location of the files being accessed, multiple files being read at once didn't increase from the base time it took to read a single file when I was did some very basic benchmarking.

Comment: The question still burning is why doesn't more than one file get opened and read at once? With multiprocessing, I'm expecting each process to open up a file then and these open files should then be visible in 'lsof' output regardless of how the data is actually pulled from the disk?

Comment: @LukeB Did you see that behavior with both `multiprocessing` and `gevent`, or just `gevent`? When I run similar code to yours with `multiprocessing.Pool`, I do see `cpu_count()` files open concurrently.

Comment: Worked when I used pool.map() in multiprocessing.